# RapidSSL nginx Certificate issuer is me

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, openssl

I have baught the SSL certificate from RapidSSL.
I have concatenated the chain files of RapidSSL CA and GeoTrust Global CA
But when I check it on http://www.sslshopper.com/
I have this :

```
The certificate is self-signed. Users will receive a warning when accessing this site unless the certificate is manually added as a trusted certificate to their web browser. You can fix this error by buying a trusted SSL certificate
```

Nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain.com;
    index index.php;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/www/domain.com/domain.com.crt;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/www/domain.com.ca;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to use `ssl_client_certificate`?

the usual way to use multiple ssl-certs in a chain in nginx is to **use the right order (server-cert FIRST)**: cat domain.com.crt rapidssl.ca geotrust.ca > domain.cert.combined and the use

```
ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/www/domain.com/domain.cert.combined
```

;

Comment: that file was empty anyway, removing it doesn't add anything